# Flexslider carousel stops too early

Tags: jquery, flexslider

I have create a slider for videos with Flexslider. I have synchrone a carousel for the preview thumbs. Now had the last item in the carousel will stop too early. See image. How can I fix this? It should be aligned with the big video.

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a JSFiddle, or post your code?

Comment: Yes, sorry. Just forget it!

Comment: @DarkAshelin http://jsfiddle.net/7Wq4a/6 I can't edit it in the answer.